# Programmatically Save Related Products

Tags: magento-1.7, product, catalog, event-observer

I need to set a particular product as related product for all the products.Here is the code that I've tried.

```
$product=$observer->getProduct();
$id=52;
$data=array(
            $id=>array(
                'position'=>2
            )
        );
$p=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
$p->setRelatedLinkData($data);
$p->save();
```

But I get error

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached,
>   aborting! in
>   /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php
>   on line 205

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: what event are you observing? sounds like you ended up with a recursion in there...

Comment: Tried both catalog_product_save_after & catalog_product_save_before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `catalog_product_save_before`... and update the code so it doesn't end up in an infinite loop.

```
$product=$observer->getProduct();
$id=52;
$data=array(
            $id=>array(
                'position'=>2
            )
        );
$product->setRelatedLinkData($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution solved my problem. I just commented the:

> "zend_extension = "d:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc9.dll"

in php.ini file. This extension was limiting the stack to 100 so I disabled it. The recursive function is now working as anticipated.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to add this product dynamically to the product collection every time the related products are loaded. This way you don't need to save all your products and have more flexibility:

1. Observe `eav_collection_abstract_load_before`
2. Check if it is the related products collection:

   ```
   $c = $observer->getCollection();
   if ($c instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Link_Product_Collection &&
       $c->getLinkModel()->getLinkTypeId() === Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Link::LINK_TYPE_RELATED
   ) {
   ```
3. If so, add the product to the collection with an additional condition:

   ```
   $c->getSelect()->orWhere($c->getConnection()->prepareSqlCondition('e.entity_id', 52);
   ```

Of course you won't hard code the product id `52` like this, but retrieve it from configuration or somewhere else.