# Magento Communitty setting up related products

Tags: magento-1.9, products-management

Is there a way to setup related products to do a two way relationship instead of just a one way relationship.

If I relate product a with b then b should be related to a automatically.

I get my products from an API and the API doesn't allow me to map products together that are the same except for flavor together.  I'm hoping to be able to map the similar products together using related products.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but it requires customization. In general, this is how you set up related products programmatically: [Programmatically Save Related Products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13527/programmatically-save-related-products). You follow up with `$product->save()`.

However, note that if you hook onto `catalog_product_save_before` to load other products (for the two-way link) to save, you'll have an infinite loop of `catalog_product_save_before`. So, I recommend hooking onto `catalog_product_save_after` event to trigger another process that will take care of the reverse association.

Some pseudocode:

```
// In the observer...
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
if ($product->getRelatedLinkData() && !empty($product->getRelatedLinkData()) {
    $this->runMyCustomMethod($product);
}        

// In runMyCustomMethod($product)
$id = $product->getId(); // entity ID of the original product that got saved
$associatedIds = $prouct->getRelatedLinkData();

// Go through each of the products that got associated to the original product
// and save a reverse link
foreach ($associatedIds as $productId => $stuff) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId); 
    $newData = ...; // Get this product's related links and append $id to it
    $product->setRelatedLinkData($newData);
    $product->save();
}
// Note: this process can get very expensive due to each product model loads
```

This is using the factory method to load the product objects individually. I recommend creating a resource model and take advantage of `Varien_Db_Select` instead for direct updates, instead of `getModel()`.